# Create Parent-Child tree JSON with IDs not following each other

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a tree with database records, 
at first I used the following code :

[Create Parent-Child tree JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728841/create-parent-child-tree-json)

Which worked fine, but since I can Insert and Delete nodes of the tree in my database, the function isn't working anymore.
As you can see, now I can have the first Element with for Id 90 and childrens width smaller Ids.

```
var arry = [{
    "parentId": null,
    "moduleId": 90
 },
 {
    "parentId": 1,
    "moduleId":65
 },
 {
    "parentId": 1,
    "moduleId": 91
 },
 {
    "parentId": 65,
    "moduleId": 66
 },
 {
    "parentId": 66,
    "moduleId": 79   
 },
 {
    "parentId": 90, 
    "moduleId": 1 
 }
];
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1c20hb7w/

Of course, I can't change IDs in my database (It would be too simple).
So I would like to know how to makes everything work, if you have a track to help me.. 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more complicated tree I'd suggest a recursive approach, as example:

```js
var arry=[{parentId:null,moduleId:90},{parentId:1,moduleId:65},{parentId:1,moduleId:91},{parentId:65,moduleId:66},{parentId:66,moduleId:79},{parentId:90,moduleId:1}];

function recursiveTree(array) {
  function getChildren(parents, input) {
    return parents.map(parent => {
      const children = input.filter(x => x.parentId === parent.moduleId);
      parent.children = children;
      if(children.length === 0) {
        return parent;
      } else {
        parent.children = getChildren(children, input);
        return parent;
      }
    }) 
  }

  const roots = array.filter(x => x.parentId === null);
  
  return getChildren(roots, array);
}

var r = recursiveTree(arry)
console.log('array', r);
console.log('result', JSON.stringify(r))
```

Comment: It works perfectly, Thank you ! I tried to find resources on the recursive approach but it's hard to find and I don't really know where to start, if you have resources on recursion for beginners, I take! 
thanks again

Comment: @abvlle Hi. I don't know any kind of resource to learn exclusively recursion. Recursion is widely used in funcional programming such as `lisp`, `clojure` or `scala`. So, training a funcional programming language will increase your recursion feelings naturally. And hey, besides of accept an answer, you can either upvote it if you found it useful. =)